# Handle two different JSON types in Android

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

The API I'm working with has two different types of JSON depending on if the object is filled or not. If it is filled it is a JSON object, else it is a JSON array, how would I go about handling this in Retrofit?

**Empty**
`"errors": []`

**Not empty**

```
"errors": {
        "licence": [
            "You have too many points on your licence"
        ],
        "general": [
            "An error occurred during your verification, please contact support"
        ]
    }
```

How would I go about handling this with Retrofit to not cause errors whenever I'm handling the response?

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with retrofit, but with the JSON Deserializer you use.
I guess you're using the GSON adapter for retrofit. Then you have no alternative than to write custom deserializer for your response.

Let me show you a example (in Kotlin):

1. At first we must create a base class for the response. In kotlin there is are awesome construct called sealed class. For java i would suggest to create two classes which are representing both states (empty and has data) and inherit from a base class.

```
sealed class ErrorResponse {
    object Empty : ErrorResponse()
    data class ApiError(val licence: List<String>, val general: List<String>) : ErrorResponse()
}

//make sure you call function in the retrofit interface is set to the correct type
@GET("errors")
fun getErrorResponse() : Call<ErrorResponse>
```

2. Then we must create our deserializer and register it to the gson instance. So we can tell gson how objects of type n should be handled.

```
class ErrorResponseDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<ErrorResponse> {

    override fun deserialize(json: JsonElement, typeOfT: Type, context: JsonDeserializationContext): ErrorResponse {
        return when(json) {
            is JsonObject -> {
                context.deserialize<ErrorResponse.ApiError>(json, ErrorResponse.ApiError::class.java)
            }
            else -> ErrorResponse.Empty
        }
    }
}

//create gson instance and register the deserializer
val gson = GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(ErrorResponse::class.java, ErrorResponseDeserializer())
            .create()

//use own gson instance for the gson converter factory
Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            ...
```

3. Last step is to check what state the error response have.

```
//or use rxjava / coroutines etc for the response handling
override fun onResponse(call: Call<ErrorResponse>, response: Response<ErrorResponse>) {
                        val body = response.body()

                        when(body) {
                            is ErrorResponse.Empty -> {
                                //TODO handle empty array state
                            }
                            is ErrorResponse.ApiError -> {
                                //TODO handle api errors or whatever you want
                                val general = body.general //smart cast kotlin <3
                            }
                        }
                    }
```